# Dynamic query construction using hibernate or spring jdbc

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-jdbc

We are dessigning a system where we want to construct the query dynamically and then using that query we need to retrieve data too.

1) We have select clause table having information of all field that we need to select.
2) We have from clause table where we have all table name store
3) We have where clause table.

Using all these table we need to create a query. and then after running the query we need to get the data too.

Please suggest if you have any example to handle such requirement using spring or hibernate.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You will not want to do string concatenation to create your queries.  You could use the criteria api, but I found it unwieldy at best.  I would suggest you look at [querydsl](http://www.querydsl.com/).